# How do you debug a Microsoft Word web add-in with vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Visual Studio has a template for a Word web add-in. Clicking 'Start' opens Word with the add-in loaded, and allows for immediate debugging of the front-end javascript in the IDE.

[image]

Word was running the add-in in ie11.

With this project, the only options I've found are debugging with 'f12' debugger located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe (or System32).

[image]

I installed the latest version of windows to get access to the new Windows Terminal. This update also switched the Word add-in to load in edge instead of ie11, which requires the new Microsoft Edge Developer Tools.

[image]

I would like to get access to the functionality Visual Studio provides for debugging front-end code via an IDE instead of f12/edge developer tools. I cannot find out how Visual Studio allows this debugging as all of the properties are hidden away as settings in .sln and web.config etc.

Is there any way to debug this add-in with Visual Studio/vscode (preferrably vscode)?

Comment: Note: I've also raised this in the Word-Add-in-GettingStartedFabricReact github repo here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-GettingStartedFabricReact/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can use VSCode for debugging but all debugging methods depends on external browsers like chrome, IE, edge debugger. I believe you do not want to perform this in VSCode.

This method will help you in some way. But I am sure you can manage this.

Step 1. Create a word web addin using Yeoman generator. Official link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

They use nodejs and you can choose Angular / React / JS to build your addin.

The advantage is it will give you the flexibility to debug in **any IDE** .

**Caveat:** As I said above you can easily build the Addin with the help of web technology.

Step 2: **Debugging:**  either you can use VSCODE Debugging functionality or use the browser

Step 3: **If you choose browser:** Go to sources > Choose Webpack > Select the .ts or /js file and set the breakpoint. Screenshot below for your kind reference.

[image]

**note:** I have selected Angular from office generator to build the addin. Then you can see the webpack under the sources. I believe this is the same for any technology.

Hope this will help you.